# What is the best way to close multiple running versions of your swing app in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, java

When developing swing apps, it doesnt take a while to get to this situation:
[image]

It is a pain to close each version of my swing app manually. There must be a command to close all java swing apps at once.

Comment: `shutdown -r` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close all java processes use:

```
taskkill /IM java.exe
```

Or if this is not enough, use force:

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe /T
```

If you are launching another java variant than `java.exe`, replace its name
in the command.

Comment: I may have considered it to be understood for granted, but the java programs are being run from eclipse directly. I think this is why I get "ERROR: The process "java.exe" cannot be found. I cannot close all my java apps this way

Comment: Use Task Manager to search for the Java processes. It can also be `javaw.exe` or `javaws.exe` or other. You may also use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to locate the process owning a window by dragging the cross-hair icon over the window,